# xamarin.forms ImageSource.FromFile slow

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using a relative layout inside ContentPage.

within the relative layout it i create childern such as labels, button, and image from from file (using the ImageSource.FromFile method), where the image is all over the screen (like backgroundImage)

what i see when presenting the page,is a black screen with all the labels and button and after one second the image appears.

I can't use BackgroundImage property because the file is created dynamically at runtime...

What is the solution for presenting the image at the same time as the labels / buttons ?

Answer (score 2):

You may try using FFImageLoading. This library can be used with Xamarin.Forms and faster than
 https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading